# VBA code to invoke "Clean Up Folder" in Outlook 2010?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Does anyone know the VBA code to invoke the "Clean Up Folder" Outlook 2010 command on the right-click menu when right-clicking on a folder?

I have gotten this far in VBA code to get to the folders I want to clean up:

```
Private Sub CleanUpAllFolders()
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Set Folders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders
For Each Folder In Folders
    If Left(Folder.Name, 1) = "_" Then
        ' Clean up folder... how do I invoke that command from VBA on this folder?
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, I can't see any method on the Folder object itself that lets me invoke "Clean Up Folder".

How do I invoke one of those right-click menu commands on the current selected folder in VBA?

Comment: I don't see it anywhere obvious in the object model either. You could try the old standby of recording a macro while executing a cleanup of a folder. Looking at the code in the recorded macro might give you a hint regarding where to start looking

Comment: This is a great question that I have been looking at hoping to see some feedback. I cant find anything useful in the object model or via google. @barrow,  unlike Excel Outlook doesn't offer a macro recorder function

Comment: @brettdj Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding. Outlook sometimes seems like the unloved step-child of the Office family

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to test this, but from what I read this might work.

First find the **idMso** value for the command. Use this to find the value:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582

Then use `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(idMso)` to execute the command. Good luck.

Comment: This post might provide more assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600181/outlook-object-model-hooking-to-the-conversation-cleanup-feature